# Laravel weird Eloquent error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I cannot find the problem in this code.

```
public function dovoljenjaZaposlenega($id)
     {  
        echo Dovoljenja::find($id)->naziv;
     }
```

When I do this, i get a following **error**:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

But when i just echo **$id** out, it's working

```
public function dovoljenjaZaposlenega($id)
          { 
           echo $id;
          }
```

But even more weird is, that if i replace $id with actual number it's working again..

```
public function dovoljenjaZaposlenega($id)
     {  
        echo Dovoljenja::find(2)->naziv; // Some number..
     }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `var_dump($id)` it might contains spaces or hidden characters

Comment: What do you get if `var_dump(Dovoljenja::find(4)->naziv);`

Comment: @Baba i get regular string, but when i replace "4" with $id i get Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong .. you just need to basically check for errors. `Dovoljenja::find($id);` would only return an object if the `$id` exists

Try this experiment with id `2` and `4`

```
function dovoljenjaZaposlenega($id) {
    $find = Dovoljenja::find($id);
    $find = is_object($find) ? $find->naziv : "Am empty";
    echo $find;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I had some id's with value of "0", but i didnt think that would be a problem..

Comment: @user1141356 .. its always good to check for errors .. that is best practice